# Get the text inside a span using jquery

Tags: jquery, text, html

I have a span tag like this `<span id="myspan">1234 <a id="change"> </a> </span>` and now i want to get 1234 using jquery. Any sugeestion?? If my span has an id??

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#change').parent('span').text()
```

or

```
$('span').text();
```

or

```
 $('#myspan').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.text()`! Try this:

```
$('span').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('span').html();` will also give you whatever is inside the tag/id you supply.

Answer (score 0):

try to map : collecting them into an array instead of two calls to $:

```
var texts = $('span').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue
});
texts[0]; // "Some text followed by "
alert(texts[0]);
```

Hope it will help