# send data from twig to controller using ajax in symfony 3.4

Tags: json, ajax, symfony

i want to  send data from a view (Twig) to controller without refreshing the page so i used ajax , in order to pass data to a specific controller action . 
this is my ajax code in the twig file :

```
   <script>     
        var data = {request : $('#content').val()};

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{{ path('AjoutAjax') }}",
          data: data,
          success: function (data, dataType) {
            alert(data);
          },
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
          }
        });
</script>
```

this is my twig file :

```
<div class="column text-lg">Subtotal: <span class="text-medium" id="content">
```

this is my controller action :

```
    public function AjoutAjaxAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('request');
        echo $data;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $reservation = $em->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier')->find(11);
        $reservation->setTotal($data);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('@reservation/Default/afficherPanier.html.twig');
    }
```

and this is the routing file

```
affichage:
    path:     /afficherPanier/{iduser}
    defaults: { _controller: reservationBundle:Default:afficherPanier }
AjoutAjax:
    path:     /ajoutAjax
    defaults: { _controller: reservationBundle:Default:AjoutAjax }
```

the problem is :

1/ it's not sending data to the controller action because when i tried with the path 'AjoutAjax'  it's not showing the echo '$data' .

2/with any path should i test with 'affichage' or  'AjoutAjax' to know that is working ? 
'

Comment: You've got alerts and echo's already to debug. You've done 50% of the job, but you don't feed us with what those echo's and alerts tell you? Feed that in your question so we can help you.

Comment: it's not sending data to the controller action because when i tried with the path 'AjoutAjax' and it's not showing the echo '$data

Comment: First, you should check if the data is being sent by looking at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Find the AJAX request being fired and look at the parameters sent.
In your controller, use `dump($data); die();` instead of echo, you will get more details

Comment: Instead of `$('#content').val()` try `$('#content').text()` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993690/get-the-text-inside-a-span-using-jquery

Since you are not sending data = this is not symfony fault. To check POST requests you can use for example Postman app/extension

Answer (score 0):

I'm no front-end dev but but i think you should use `.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.val()` on a span element

https://api.jquery.com/text/#text